# Clone data from one to another database column in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, clone

I have two columns `quantity` and `remaining_quantity` in my stock table. I wanted to copy same data from `quantity` to `remaining_quantity` while doing a create function. Is there any function in Laravel for that?

Comment: You want to set `remaining_quantity` to the same value as `quantity` when object is created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by creating an observer.

1- Create a folder called `observers` in you `app` folder.

2- Create a file named `MyModelObserver.php` for example `StockObserver.php`.

3- Prepare your class like the following:

```
<?php
namespace App\Observers;


class StockObserver
{
    //
}
```

Inside that class you can create `creating`, `created`, `updated`, `updated`, `deleting`, `deleted`, `saving` and `saved` methods. Which their jobs are obvious from their names.
For more details see => https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events

For example the following code will do something everytime an object of `Stock` model is created.

```
<?php
namespace App\Observers;


use App\Stock;

class StockObserver
{
    public function created(Stock $stock)
    {
        $stock->remaining_quantity = $stock->quantity;
        $stock->save()
    }
}
```

But all these code won't be effective unless you observe that in the `AppServiceProvide` .. so in the `boot` method in `AppServiceProvider` write the following.

```
\App\Stock::observe(\App\Observers\StockObserver::class);
```

That's it .. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a few different ways to do that. An easy, dirty way would be to just have two queries,

```
$quantity = StockTable::find($id);
StockTable::create([
    'remaining_quantity' => $quantity->quantity
]);
```

So you grab the record you want to copy a bit of, and then set it as the remaining quantity on your creating record.